# How do I make a TextMate macro to open all files in my project that match a regular expression?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

How do I make a TextMate macro to open all files in my project that match the regular expression,  "/todolist/i"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in perl, by creating a command.  It requires to have a file in the project already open in order for the hotkey to work.  Perhaps there is no way around this, since while a file is not open in the project, the command is greyed out in the Bundle menu.  Maybe there's a hotkey to open *some* file in the project (or some other way to get the command un-greyed)?  I'd like to just press a sequence of hotkeys.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use File::Find;

my $dir = dirname($ENV{'TM_DIRECTORY'});
my $textmate_path = $ENV{'TM_SUPPORT_PATH'} . '/bin/mate';
find(sub { system(qw/mate/, $File::Find::name) if /TODOLIST/ }, $dir);
die;
```